# Improving WebDriver's error messages

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

We have webdriver tests written in Java that are run continuously and when errors occur, team members who are not familiar with WebDriver or Java are sometimes reviewing the errors. We're finding that it can be slow and difficult to understand what went wrong with the standard error messaging and are trying to think of ways outside of the box to augment the existing error messaging. We already have videos and screenshots of the tests.

I'm wondering if anyone has implemented anything that makes the error messaging in WebDriver more readable by "lay people"

Thanks!

Comment: What testing framework do you use? TestNG? Junit?

Comment: When you `assert` something, JUnit will allow you to pass in a message to show if that assertion fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually write custom exceptions to wrap the webdriver exceptions. Page objects throw these custom exceptions when elements are not found/visible/enabled etc. I try not to throw webdriver exceptions in my (Nunit) tests, this way test reports can also be published to non-techs like managers etc.

Comment: Cool, how do you ensure the custom exceptions are somewhat readable?

Comment: For eg: A page object offers a service `MenuNavigateTo(string menuItem)`, which throws custom `MenuNotFoundException` with message `The menu item {menuItem} was not found in the menu`. This exception is raised when WebDriver throws either a `NoSuchElementException` or `ElementNotVisibleException` exception. As per the [page objects](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) pattern, *Facing away from the developer, they (Page Objects) should be the only thing that has a deep knowledge of the structure of the HTML of a page ...*